# Android Upload a file via OKHTTP not using MultiPart

Tags: android, networking, file-upload, upload, okhttp

This is the code that I have to upload a file:

```
fun uploadFile(oid: String, file: Attachment, mime: String, callback: Callback): Call {
    val url = getURL(XelionOKHttpAPIRestLinks.UPLOAD_FILE.replace("__OID__", oid))
    var mediaType = mime.toMediaType()
    var body = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM).addFormDataPart("file", file.originalLocation,
            RequestBody.create(mediaType, file.originalLocation)).build()
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).headers(setHeaderUpload(mime, file.commonName, file.size.toString())).post(body).build()
    val call = client.newCall(request)
    call.enqueue(callback)
    return call
}
```

Which works perfectly on my part. BUT the server does not support MultiPart. So I need to send the file in one go. How is this possible?

I also tried with HTTPConnection:

```
     var async = object : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String {
            val url = URL(getURL(XelionOKHttpAPIRestLinks.UPLOAD_FILE.replace("__OID__", oid)))
            try {
                val urlConnection: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                var nameOnly = attachment.commonName.split("/")
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST")
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true)
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "xelion " + XelionPreferences.INSTANCE.authToken)
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", mime)
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + nameOnly.last() + "\"")
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", attachment.size.toString())
                urlConnection.connect()
                val fileOutput = FileOutputStream(file)
                var decodedBytes = Base64.decode(attachment.contentsB64String, Base64.NO_WRAP)
                fileOutput.write(decodedBytes)
                fileOutput.close()
                var responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode()
                callback.sendData("")
            } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return ""
        }
    }
    async.execute()
}
```

But for this I get this issue:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: content-length promised 318848 bytes, but received 0
```

What am I missing/getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple tries, using this in my AsyncTask made it work:

```
val url = URL(getURL(XelionOKHttpAPIRestLinks.UPLOAD_FILE.replace("__OID__", oid)))
            var baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            try {
                val urlConnection: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                var nameOnly = attachment.commonName.split("/")
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST")
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true)
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true)
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "xelion " + XelionPreferences.INSTANCE.authToken)
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", mime)
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + nameOnly.last() + "\"")
                urlConnection.connect()
                var decodedBytes = Base64.decode(attachment.contentsB64String, Base64.DEFAULT)
                urlConnection.getOutputStream().write(decodedBytes)

                val `is`: InputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream()
                val b = ByteArray(1024)

                while (`is`.read(b) !== -1) baos.write(b)

                urlConnection.disconnect()
                callback.sendData("")
            } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is about `getBytes()`

Be careful when you use it because you have to pass the character encoding parameter like `.getBytes("UTF-8")`

If you don't pass any parameter it will use the system default.

Please do like :

fileOutput.write("**YOUR DECODED STRING**".getBytes("UTF-8"));

Comment: Where? I tried `attachment.contentsB64String.getBytes("UTF-8")` but getBytes for a string is a "unresolved refference". Also the same if I try it on the "decodedBytes" (which is a byte[] )

Comment: I used: " var decodedBytes = attachment.contentsB64String.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)" but on urlConnection.getResponseCode I still get the same PROTOCOL EXCEPTION ERROR